# make list android

Tags: android

I want to create some a dynamic list some thing like hash table

so I can put a key with value or I read list

I want to save it and able to read it when pogrom started .

is it possible  ?

Comment: do you know about java file output stream and stuff??? this is really basic stuff that you are looking for. Can you improve your question and describe what problem you are having??? your post shows lack of effort which is not very constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Seems like you are looking for [`HashMap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html)
2. You will need to serialize / deserialize the map to save/load it.

Answer (score 0):

Question: is it possible? Answer: yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

you are asking for something like hash table where you can save key value pairs you can use also shared preferences for that.

http://as400samplecode.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-shared-preferences-example_12.html